# Reference a column that is not inserted in the RETURNING clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

These are the existing tables in my database. The field 'record_prt_id' in Expense and Revenue table is a foreign key that relates to the field 'id' in the Record table.

-- Record

| id | amount | record_date | property_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $100.0 | 10/15/2022 | 1 |
| 2 | $150.0 | 12/22/2022 | 1 |
| 3 | $2000.0 | 10/1/2022 | 2 |
| 4 | $1500.0 | 11/1/2022 | 1 |

-- Expense

| record_ptr_id | expense_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Repair |
| 2 | Water |

-- Revenue

| record_ptr_id | revenue_type |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Rent |
| 4 | Reimbursement |

I need to insert these 2 new expenses:

-- Expense_temp

| amount | record_date | expense_type | property_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $50.0 | 9/13/2022 | Electricity | 2 |
| $100.0 | 8/15/2022 | Trash | 3 |

I would first need to insert these 2 expenses into the record table, and then the expense table. The final result would look like this:

-- Record

| id | amount | record_date | property_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $100.0 | 10/15/2022 | 1 |
| 2 | $150.0 | 12/22/2022 | 1 |
| 3 | $2000.0 | 10/1/2022 | 2 |
| 4 | $1500.0 | 11/1/2022 | 1 |
| 5 | $50.0 | 9/13/2022 | 2 |
| 6 | $100.0 | 8/15/2022 | 3 |

-- Expense

| record_ptr_id | expense_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Repair |
| 2 | Water |
| 5 | Electricity |
| 6 | Trash |

Here is my query:

```
WITH inserted_records AS (
INSERT INTO record(amount, record_date, property_id)
SELECT e.amount, e.record_date, e.property_id 
FROM expense_tmp e 
RETURNING id, /* this doesn't work */ e.expense_type
)
INSERT INTO expense(record_prt_id, expense_type) 
SELECT r.id, r.expense_type
FROM inserted_records r;
```

But postgres gives me this error

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "e"
> LINE 5: RETURNING id, e.expense_type

I need to get the expense_type column in the RETURNING clause for the second INSERT statement. How do I accomplish this?

**UPDATE:**

A working solution (suggested by @mwalter) is to insert the ids into the expense_tmp table before inserting them into the record table.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE expense_tmp_seq;

SELECT setval('expense_tmp_seq', (SELECT currval('record_seq')));

WITH expense_tmp_with_id AS (
    SELECT nextval('expense_tmp_seq') AS id, record_date, expense_type, property_id
    FROM expense_tmp
),
inserted_records AS (
    INSERT INTO record(id, amount, record_date, property_id)
    SELECT nextval('record_seq'), e.amount, e.record_date, e.property_id 
    FROM expense_tmp e 
    RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO expense(record_ptr_id, expense_type) 
SELECT s.id, s.expense_type
FROM inserted_records r INNER JOIN expense_tmp_with_id s ON r.id = s.id;
```

Comment: `RETURNING` can only fetch values from the table being inserted into, it will not see `e.expense_type`. The only way I can see to do this is put the `SELECT e.amount, e ...` into it's own CTE and then use those values to do the inserts into `record` and `expense`.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please clarify? The records in table expense_temp have no ids. I'm still not clear about how to link the inserted ids, which are only available after insert, back to the rows in the table expense_tmp. How could I do this with a CTE?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a more CTE's statements to the transaction and generate the insert ID before insert the records to avoid some small problems.

```
WITH select_query AS (
   SELECT e.amount, e.record_date, e.property_id, e.expense_type ,nextval('record_seq'::regclass) insertid
FROM expense_tmp e 
),inserted_records AS (
INSERT INTO record(id ,amount, record_date, property_id)
SELECT e.insertid ,e.amount, e.record_date, e.property_id 
FROM select_query e 
RETURNING id, /* this doesn't work */ e.expense_type
)
INSERT INTO expense(record_prt_id, expense_type) 
SELECT r.id, a.expense_type
FROM inserted_records r 
JOIN select_query a ON a.insertid = r.id ;
```

Comment: Thank you. I think nextval should work for my case. However, it increments the id every time we call it, so the ids generated in the CTE will be different from the ids generated by the INSERT clause.